# Ruby On Rails 3, order by the combination of two values in different models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sql-order-by, conditional-statements

Hi
I wonder if there's a way to do this without involving advance SQL code?

Model 1.
Product
:has_many prices

Model 2.
Retailer
:has_many prices
:has_one profile

Model 3.
Price - price:integer
:belongs_to :retailers
:belongs_to :products

Model 4.
Profile - Shippingcost:integer
:belongs_to :retailers

I want to be able to sort by(:price+:shippingCost), I know how to do this with SQL, with left joins and creating a "(bla + bla2) AS totalPrice and sort it by totalPrice, but is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: check out the meta_where gem. Ernies objective is to reduce/remove the necessity of sql code withing ruby/rails programming... have a look at     http://metautonomo.us/projects/metawhere/ and try his helpers to see if you can get it done without sql-code. Still if you need a non-left join you will probably end up in having to ".join('xxxx')" with xxxx beeing a pure sql-snippet to define the correct joining of the tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,ething like that. But it is too deep nested

```
Product.includes(:prices => {:retailer => :profile}).select("products.*, (prices.price + profiles.shippingcost) AS sum).order(:sum)
```

Comment: Hi fl00r,
I manage to do this.

@price = Price.joins(:retailer, :retailer => :profile)

The log sais.

SELECT `prices`.* FROM `prices` INNER JOIN `retailers` ON `retailers`.`id` = `prices`.`retailer_id` INNER JOIN `profiles` ON `profiles`.`retailer_id` = `retailers`.`id`

But it's missing the AS and order BY... The final code below show how it should look

SELECT (`prices`.price + `profiles`.shippingCost) AS totalPrice FROM `prices` INNER JOIN `retailers` ON `retailers`.`id` = `prices`.`retailer_id` INNER JOIN `profiles` ON `profiles`.`retailer_id` = `retailers`.`id` ORDER BY totalPrice

Comment: The solution:

@price = Price.select('`prices`.*, (`prices`.price + `profiles`.shippingCost) AS totalPrice').joins(:retailer, :retailer => :profile).order(:totalPrice).all

The problem I have now is that I'm getting a nil exception when I try to use XML and JSON...